# QGIS Version 3.34 ‘Prizren’ is 'not responding' on MacBook Pro

Tags: qgis

Over the past few days, QGIS has not been working well with my MacBook Pro M1 (MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1). I can upload some shapefiles, but the software freezes whenever I'm doing some process (geocoding, joining, etc.). In the activity monitor, I receive a 'not responding' error and need to force quit the program. I tried to update the software, deleted it from my computer, and reinstalled it, but the same problem reappeared.